# Docker: how to execute a batch file when container starts and keep the user in cmd / session

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, docker, dockerfile

I'm using Docker on Windows 2016 Server TP4 with a Windows container.

**When the container gets started, I want to execute a certain initialization script (init.bat) but also want to keep the user logged into the container session (in cmd).**

With this dockerfile:

```
FROM windowsservercore
ADD sources /init
ENTRYPOINT C:/init/init.bat
```

and this init.bat (which is supposed to run inside the container on startup):

```
mkdir C:\myfolder
echo init end
```

and this startup call for the container:

```
docker run -it test/test cmd
```

**the init.bat batch file gets executed inside the container, but the user does not stay logged in the container, but the container exits (with exit code 0).**

I don't quite understand why it exits. From how I understand the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options):

> If the image also specifies an ENTRYPOINT then the CMD or COMMAND get
>   appended as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT.

the `cmd` command should get appended to the entrypoint, which is my init script, but it doesn't.

I also tried this syntax, but it does not make a difference.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["C:/init/init.bat"]
```

If I remove the ENTRYPOINT from the dockerfile and start the container with the `cmd` command, I stay in the session and I can of course run the init.bat script manually and it works, but I want it to run automatically.

When I work with Ubuntu containers, I usually use `supervisord` to execute any initialization scripts, and bin/bash (which equivalents to `cmd` on Windows) as the command.
I am not sure how to do the same on a Windows container though.

Comment: You can try `start /b cmd /k "docker run -it test/test cmd"` in your batch-file

Comment: @DennisvanGils I just tried this and added the line to my init.bat, but it still exits. This is the output when I start run the container: http://snag.gy/la4q3.jpg

Comment: @DennisvanGils Just to be clear: the init.bat is being executed inside the container, not outside. (Not sure why I would call "docker run" from inside the container. But I think you meant: start /b cmd /k "c:\init\init.bat"). Anyway, I tried both, did not yet succeed. Usually, when I work with Linux containers, I use supervisord to start an init shell script, and the bin/bash as the command. But not sure how to do it on a Windows container right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

instead of the ENTRYPOINT you can try putting something like this in your Dockerfile:

`CMD C:\init\init.bat && cmd`

Comment: Perfect, that works! Note that I have a Windows container though, so it should be: `CMD C:\init\init.bat && cmd`. I edited your answer regarding that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is not working for me... anybody could think of something? is there a log I could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar case. Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:4.7.1 

run mkdir c:\WorkSpace
copy ./CreateFolder.bat /WorkSpace

CMD c:\\WorkSpace\\CreateFolder.bat

ENTRYPOINT POWERSHELL Write-Host Folder created ; \
while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

This isn't working. The container stays up but the folder isn't created.

Whereas if i do the opposite :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:4.7.1 

run mkdir c:\WorkSpace
copy ./CreateFolder.bat /WorkSpace

ENTRYPOINT c:\\WorkSpace\\CreateFolder.bat

CMD POWERSHELL Write-Host Folder created ; \
while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

---- this is working. The container stays up and the folder is created.